# Convergence of a sequence of powers of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $n = 1,2,...$ be functions that converge uniformly to a  function $f$, which is bounded. I wish to show that $f_n(t)^m$ converge uniformly on $[0,1]$ to $f(t)^m$ for any positive integer $m$. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note first $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)^m = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (f_n(x)^m - f_{n-1}(x)^m)$$ where $f_0 \equiv 0$.

Now let $M \ge |f(x)|$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.  Fix $\epsilon > 0$.  Then we can pick $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, $|f_n(x)| \le M+\epsilon$ by uniform convergence.  Hence for $n-1 \ge N$, $|f_n(x)|^m, |f_{n-1}(x)|^m \le (M+\epsilon)^m$, so $|f_n(x)^m - f_{n-1}(x)^m| \le 2(M+\epsilon)^m$.  Since this bound holds for all but finitely many $M$, we can apply the Weierstrass M-test to see that $f_n(x)^m$ converges uniformly.  Since clearly $f_n(x)^m \to f(x)^m$ pointwise, we are done.

There is probably a "nicer" proof that doesn't use the M test, but this is what I came up with.

EDIT: Here's the nicer proof.  I actually misapplied the M test above (look it up and you'll see why).

$f_n \to f$ uniformly.  Fix $\epsilon > 0$.  There exists $N$ such that for $n \ge N$, $$f(x) - \epsilon < f_n(x) < f(x) + \epsilon$$.  Let $M \ge |f(x)|$.  Hence $$f(x)^m - O(M \epsilon) < f_n(x)^m < f(x)^m + O(M \epsilon),$$ where I use the notation $O(M \epsilon)$ to mean this term is bounded by some constant multiple of $M \epsilon$.  Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we're done.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes a lot of sense. I hadn't thought to write the limit as the sum in your first line.